# Pandas concat results are misaligned with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I had a dataframe for fitting ML algo with both categorial and numerical fatures.
So I splitted this df and converted categorial features with one-hot encoding and now I have numpy matrix which I have to join back to df with numerical features so first row of numerical dataframe will get first matrix row as new features.

Given to documentation and results of googling 'join dataframes' command

```
pd.concat([X_numerical, pd.DataFrame(numpy_matrix)], axis=1)
```

But I am getting this - like 'axis' param was ignored (I cleaned up all raw data from np.nan):

[image: result example]

What am I doing wrong? I expected to get resulting dataframe without these NaNs, with df rows concatenated one by one with matrix rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a possible issue with index mis-alignment. The best thing to do is to reset the index:

```
df = pd.concat([
       X_numerical.reset_index(), 
       pd.DataFrame(numpy_matrix)
   ], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the problem is that these dataframe and produced numpy matrix is result of splitting original dataset into train and test parts with some random state. If I'll reset indcies I'll mess numerical and categorical features of an object

Comment: @VladimirKolenov Well, the index is the reason for the misalignment, perhaps try my edit? You can reset the index without dropping it.

Comment: thanks, seems your edit helped me. Is it correct that now I should drop column 'index' with old indecies? I'll go further with you suggestion, hope playing around indecies won't punish me later

Comment: @VladimirKolenov If you meant to drop the index column, you might as well have used reset_index(drop=True). You claim you need it as a feature. I don't know anything about your problem, but if you want to keep the index after concatenation as a column, then this is the way.

Comment: I meant that I should keep accordance between numerical and categorial features within one row after joining dataframes. If order of rows in either numerical dataframe and categorial array kept after resetting index I'm okay with that. I was afraid that after resetting index dataframe will be re-sorted and numpy array is not so I'll loose such accordance

Comment: @VladimirKolenov Ah... I see... no, resetting the index does not sort or reindex in any way, just either moves it out of the index as a column, or drops altogether. Hope that clears it :-)